# How the "Always On" setting effects CPU usage in Azure webapps

Tags: cpu, azure-web-app-service

How "Always on" setting effects CPU usage?
When "Always on" is off, the CPU usage is 0% if no one uses it. But after I set it is on, it seems CPU usage is High even no one uses it.

This image is showing the max CPU Percentage every 5 minutes in 24 hours.
[image]

This image is showing the average CPU Percentage every 5 minutes in 24 hours.
[image]

Is it normal? By the way, the images are from Azure app plan. And I have 3 webapps in the same plan. And all of them have been set "always on" to on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always On keeps the host process running. This allows your site to be more responsive to request after significant idle periods. Otherwise, once a request comes in, the App Service will have to cold boot and load into memory before responding to the request.

If you're seeing expectantly high CPU duding an "idle" period, I would start by correlating incoming requests with CPU spikes. Have a look [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-availability-performance-application-issues) in order to get a snapshot of activity that's being done while your app service is idle.

Comment: May I think my CPU is normal? Because of "Always On", the request will be posted every a few minutes. That causes the CPU usage high. Right?

Comment: Normal would depend on what's considered normal for you app. If you're app has some sort of background process, then that would be considered normal. If you suspect your app shouldn't be doing anything until it receives a request, then that's something worth investigating. Bear in mind that with AlwaysOn enabled, Azure will periodically ping your app service to ensure it's still up and running. 

That's why I suggested following https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/faq-availability-performance-application-issues to determine what you're app is doing during those high CPU loads.

Comment: But how to understand the CrashHangAnalysis.mht? Do you have any documents recommend?

Comment: Trying using [DebugDiag](https://debugdiag.com) tool. Also, there's a list of stackoverflow questions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/debugdiag) that may (or may not) help.